# Unity Raycast doesn't hit flat terrain

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-terrain

I started to learn about Unity, and I have a problem with the Raycasting. So I have this code

```
   if(Physics.Raycast(cam.position,cam.forward,out hit,100f,layer)){
    Debug.Log(hit.point);
    if(hit.transform!=this.transform){
     showPreview(hit);   
     print(hit.transform.name);
    }
   }
```

and it works fine with objects and anything else, except the terrain. If the terrain is Flat, the raycast doesn't detect it, but if I make some mountains it works fine. [Flat terrain, zero log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ajyC.png) / [Tiny hill, it detects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoXvQ.png) I tried to change the distance, but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure you are hitting the terrain within the 100 units? What happens if you rotate the camera more downwards and move closer to the terrain?

Comment: I would also triple check layers. moving scenes between project can mess up layer references

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. In the script i used the fps character as camera, and it didn't detect the vertical rotation :D Thanks for the help!